# managedObjectContext cannot be used more than once?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an app which uses CoreData to save different playlists using `MPMediaPicker`. After saving the first one, while I try to add the second one, the app crashes. Below is the entire debug queue.

Creation of the first record.

```
musicTemp = <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x13df04440>=========>prepareForSegue
saveValues()
▿ Optional<NSManagedObjectContext>
  - Some : <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x13de88a60>

musicTemp = <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x13df04440>=========>saveValues
ModelName.Rule
Optional(<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x13de88a60>)
Number of rows = 1
Number of rows = 1
musicTemp = <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x13df04440>=========>RuleViewCell
mainManagedObjectContext.save
```

End of first record creation. Start of second record creation,

```
musicTemp = <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x13dea7620>=========>prepareForSegue
saveValues()
▿ Optional<NSManagedObjectContext>
  - Some : <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x13de88a60>

musicTemp = <MPMediaItemCollection: 0x13dea7620>=========>saveValues
ModelName.Rule
Optional(<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x13de88a60>)
2016-09-10 11:39:02.469 AppName[5237:2139350] -[MPMediaItemCollection compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13df04440
All Exceptions
error: use of undeclared identifier 'mainManagedObjectContext'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

App Crashes!!

The related code which does the addition of records,

```
// Method to save the extracted values to CoreData Objects
private func saveValues() {

    // Initialize entity description
    let RuleDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Rule",inManagedObjectContext:mainManagedObjectContext!)
    let rule = Rule(entity: RuleDescription!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: mainManagedObjectContext)
    // Set object values from temporary variables
    rule.music = musicTemp!
    print("musicTemp = \(musicTemp!.count)=========>saveValues")
    // Save the object in privateManagedObjectContext
    print(NSStringFromClass(rule.classForCoder))
    print(mainManagedObjectContext)
    if ((mainManagedObjectContext?.hasChanges) != nil) {
        do {
            try mainManagedObjectContext?.save()
            print("mainManagedObjectContext.save")
        } catch let saveError as NSError {
            print("(AddRuleViewController)(mainManagedObjectContext)saveError: \(saveError), \(saveError.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

`mainManagedObjectContext` is referenced using dependency injection. I am not able to figure out why it is able to save the first time, but not again. Actually, it complains about `mainManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: Is anything subscribed to any CoreData-notifications?

Comment: Nope. I presumed, that as I save, it automatically reflects in the `NSFetchedResultsController`, and there was no need for any notifications. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you're not, as long as you work on the same MOC. I just wondered because the error-message said something about notifications. Did you try adding an exception-breakpoint to see where exactly it crashes?

Comment: `try mainManagedObjectContext?.save()` is where it crashes. And then, the console displays, 2016-09-09 10:16:51.018 AppName[4749:1894553] -[MPMediaItemCollection compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ef90390
error: use of undeclared identifier 'mainManagedObjextContext'
error: 1 errors parsing expression

Comment: Is the mainManagedObjectContext still existent at this point?

Comment: It does print Optional(<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x14edc0c70>) just before it crashes and complains that it doesn't exist. I print the context, before it is checked for `.hasChanges`

Comment: @TMob, the exact same setup works, in a different app, where the entity has multiple attributes, with given datatypes. But, in this data model, the entity has only one attribute, which is transformable. And, I intend to use this as `MPMediaItemCollection`

Comment: Where does the first 'x' come from in `mainManagedObjextContext`?

Comment: Sorry @PhillipMills, I didn't get you. What do you mean, when you say, 'x'?

Comment: "error: use of undeclared identifier 'mainManagedObjextContext'"  It seems to be reporting a mis-spelled variable name.

Comment: Yes. So, this is mentioned as I use -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1. If you notice, the entire debug queue in the question, there seem to be no problem while using `mainManagedObjectContext`, the first time, for the creation of the record. But, while I try to do it for the second time, this happens. And, I can't understand why this happens only when one of my attributes is `Transformable`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there would be a typo, as the above function, `saveValues`, is the one which is used to save the data. And, it is the same loop that occurs, the second time as well.

Comment: so you're using multiple threads and getting thread sharing violations from core data ?

Comment: Actually Sorry @PhillipMills. You seem to have pointed out something that I had missed. It is really weird, where `mainManagedObjextContext` is from. I only use `mainManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: @Wain. I'm not using multiple threads explicitly. Trying to use the same Context, to save data. And while, the first save happens without any issue, the second complains.

Comment: @PhillipMills. You had a keen eye for pointing out the typo. And, that was me printing out the `mainManagedObjectContext` during debugging. My debug command was, `po mainManagedObjextContext`, which is now corrected. So, the problem wasn't about it after all. I get the same issue, even now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be something strange with your `musicTemp` variable.

You are hard casting it (which is usually a code smell) and the error is around that variable and the object that it really contains.

The indicator is:

```
-[MPMediaItemCollection compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ef90390
```

Core Data is trying to call `compare:` on the `MPMediaItemCollection` object but `0x14ef90390` is not a `MPMediaItemCollection`.

Start poking at that variable and make sure it really is what you think it is.

Comment: So, I have removed the hard casting, which actually isn't required as my `Transformable` attribute(music) in my entity(Rule) is declared to be an `MPMediaItemCollection`(rule.music). I still do get the same error. But, what I have now observed after your suggestion is, that the instance being referred `0x14ef90390` in the error, is the first one. The second instance, is not being used!! Also, I did a bit of clean up in the code. `musicTemp` was being used globally, and is now local, where ever it is used.

Comment: or, I'd rather say, that this seems to happen because, of the way my data model is setup. I only have an entity with one attribute which is configured as `Transformable`. But, this has to be `MPMediaItemCollection`. I seem to miss something, as to how this has to be setup.

Comment: Finally figured it out, or rather not!? But, my setup is working, after an attribute was added. There is no problem now. So, either there is a bug or I don't have the right knowledge. But, there is no way CoreData works, if there is an entity with only one attribute which is `Transformable`.

Comment: Not sure if it was you or your knowledge. But, you made my day! Figured out a way out of my issue regarding CoreData. You are the "Guru". Period. :)

Comment: Although, I'd still want to know why it doesn't work, if it was the other way around.

Comment: Happy I was able to put on the right path :)  I would suggest creating a simple test project that demonstrates the crash you saw and send it to Apple (radar).  You may have found something new :)